# Utility to Visualize CPU and Memory Usage based on process tree

Tags: ps, utilities, cpu-usage

Modern desktop applications spawn several child processes to offload tasks to them. Notable examples in this regard are:

1. Google chrome - spawns a new process per tab
2. VSCode - spawns a bunch of development servers
3. Any Electron based Application

Is there a tool available, commandline or otherwise, that lets you see the consolidated CPU and memory usage in the same level/hierarchy as the existing process tree?

So the top level of this tool, for Google Chrome for eg. will yield the consolidated memory and CPU usage across all the processes it spawned on a per tab basis.

I'd be happy to write one if it does not exist. I just want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) has a tree-view. It can be accessed by pressing the `F5`-key

Comment: @TimHilt Thanks for responding. However, this does not agglomerate the stats on the group level. You still have to add up the mem usage and CPU usage of the children manually. Which is a pain for something like Chrome. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am interessted in this myself, I found this project so far, but was not able to take a further look at it https://github.com/rocky/pygtk3-pstree. It seems dead but maybe it can be re-tooled for something new.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look this up. I'll keep the question open for a couple of days to elicit more answers. If no more are forthcoming, I'll mark this as accepted.